# Keras denoising autoencoder - logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [986624,38] and labels shape [32]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to construct a denoising autoencoder for a facial recognition project, and with the initial tests i am using the cropped yalefaces dataset, with the training (noisy) images in a folder (with separate folders for each class/person inside) and the testing (regular) images in another one with the same structure. But with every test i have the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first
> dimension, got logits shape [986624,38] and labels shape [32]      [[node
> sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits
> (defined at \Desktop\projetos\conv autoencoder teste.py:75) ]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_8691]
>
> Function call stack: train_function

I am using Keras 2.6.0.

```
batch_size = 32
height = 168
width = 192
depth = 1
chanDim = -1
inputShape = (height, width, depth)

data_dir='C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\projetos\\Test1\\Data'
train_data_dir='C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\projetos\\Test1\\Test_Images\\sp_noise'
images_noisy = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(directory=train_data_dir, labels='inferred', label_mode='int',class_names=None, color_mode='grayscale', batch_size=batch_size, image_size=(height,width),shuffle=True,seed=2457,interpolation='bilinear')
images_regular = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(directory=data_dir, labels='inferred', label_mode='int',class_names=None, color_mode='grayscale', batch_size=batch_size, image_size=(height,width),shuffle=True,seed=2457,interpolation='bilinear')

datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir, class_mode='sparse', batch_size=32,target_size=(height, width),color_mode='grayscale')
val_it = datagen.flow_from_directory(data_dir, class_mode='sparse', batch_size=32,target_size=(height, width),color_mode='grayscale')

#input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(inputShape))

Input_img = Input(shape=(168,192,1))  
#Input_img = Input(shape=(None))
    
#encoding architecture
#x1 = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((168, 192, 1), input_shape=(None, 168, 192, 1))(Input_img)
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(Input_img)
x1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D( (2, 2), padding='same')(x1)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x1)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D( (2, 2), padding='same')(x2)
x3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x2)
encoded    = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D( (2, 2), padding='same')(x3)
    
# decoding architecture
x3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x3 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x3)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x3)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x2)
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x2)
x1 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x1)
decoded   = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(38, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x1)

autoencoder = Model(Input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False))

history = autoencoder.fit(
    images_noisy,
    epochs=20,
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True,
    validation_data=(images_regular))

autoencoder.summary()
```

At this point i frankly have no idea what is causing the issue. I used the dataset with the image_dataset_from_directory function in a facial recognition/classification cnn with no issues but here nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the error, the input dimension and the output dimension needs to be the same in an autoencoder. Changing the architecture of the decoder as follows will help.

```
#decoding architecture 
x3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x3 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x3)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x3)
x1 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x2)
decoded = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x1)
```